# ForEach-Object OutString, Powershell Awk Equivalents

Tags: powershell

I'm a long time Bash enthusiast trying to get my bearings with Powershell. I'm trying to do something that could easily be accomplished with Awk, but I can't seem to find a solution in Powershell documentation. I'm essentially trying to select the third value from the output of the command delimited by `/`

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CanonicalName | Select-String ".*/Example/.*"

example.local/Example/ExampleOU1
example.local/Example/ExampleOU2
```

I just want to select the last value shown here. In Bash land this could easily be accomplished by an `awk -F "/" '{print $3}'` however I'm struggling to find the equivalent in Powershell. I found `Out-String | %{ $_.Split('/')[2]; }'` which is nice, but only works if there's one object. I'm assuming I need to `ForEach-Object`, then convert to a string, then split, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `%` is an alias for `foreach-object`. There’s no need for `out-string` here if you are iterating using the pipeline and `foreach-object`. A simple way for the last value is `$output -replace '.*/'`

Comment: I decided that my answers were more harmful than helpful, so I deleted them.

Comment: You might want to try to fool around with storing the output of your command in $ADObject,  and then messing around with $ADObject.CanonicalName, if it exists.  If it does exist, it should be an array of strings.  If it is an array of strings,  Out-String is superfluous.

Comment: Perhaps `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName -Filter * | Select-Object -Property CanonicalName | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '/')[2] }`  Note: This is untested, since my PC is not in a domain.

Answer (score 0):

I almost never use out-string.  Canonicalname is a property of the object, so you need to reference that property.  This would work:

```
[pscustomobject]@{canonicalname = 'example.local/Example/ExampleOU1'} | 
  % { $_.canonicalname.Split('/')[2] }

ExampleOU1
```

There's also -split which uses regex:

```
[pscustomobject]@{canonicalname = 'example.local/Example/ExampleOU1'} | 
  % { ($_.canonicalname -split '/')[2] }
```

Paths come up so often there's a command for it:

```
[pscustomobject]@{canonicalname = 'example.local/Example/ExampleOU1'} | 
  % { split-path -leaf $_.canonicalname }
```