# How to save output of split as columns with custom headers in Powershell

Tags: powershell, split

Using the suggestion mentioned here: [split command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570778/foreach-object-outstring-powershell-awk-equivalents/64090911#64090911) I am able to split canonicalname.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties DistinguishedName, WhenCreated, Name, CanonicalName -Filter * |Select DistinguishedName, WhenCreated, Name, CanonicalName| Select-Object -Property CanonicalName | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '/') }
```

How can I display output with custom headers, split on CanonicalName, display original CanonicalName, and show the output in column format?

New Column Header would look like following:

DistinguishedName, WhenCreated, CanonicalName, Name, Servers,OSLevel1, OSLevel2,OSLevel3,Environment,Lane,OU,SubOU

For future clarity: Canonical name structure for me looks like:

```
dev.company.com/Band/Servers/Application/Development/Marketing/DevMarketing
dev.company.com/Rhel/Application/Development/Marketing/DevMarketing

Where OSLevel1 = Band
OSLevel2=Servers
OSLevel3=Application
```

For Rhel, I understand it will be in different columns.

Comment: What does the structure of one of your `CanonicalNames` look like? What is the output you are currently getting from the code you've written so far? Can you please add those to the question body?

Comment: You are definitely leaving out key details if you're going to get any help. What is servers, osleve1-3, environment, lane? Please format your question according to SO guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what data is supposed to go into which column.  You mention splitting the CanonicalName, but where do you want the data to land? Is OSLevel really supposed to mean OULevel?

What we can talk about is the ability to add properties to objects.  This can be done in different ways.  Probably the most popular is to incorporate calculated properties (expressed as hash tables) in a `Select-Object` command(s).

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * | 
Select-Object DistinguishedName,
    @{ Name = 'CanonicalBaseName'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalName.Split('/')[-1] } }
```

Obviously this is just an example, adding only 1 property. You can add as many properties as you want.  Just add a comma followed by another hash table.

If correct and you are looking to put Each OU level into a field. You may want to add an interim property by running `Select-Object` twice.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * | 
Select-Object DistinguishedName,
    @{ Name = 'CanonicalLevels'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalName.Split('/') } } |
Select-Object DistinguishedName,
    @{ Name = 'OULevel1'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalLevels[0] } },
    @{ Name = 'OULevel2'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalLevels[1] } },
    @{ Name = 'OULevel3'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalLevels[2] } }
```

In this example an array is added representing all the container levels in the CanonicalName. then passed to another `Select-Object` command that will add custom properties based on the previously added property's array indices.  Notice the CanonicalLevels property isn't output because it's not included in the 2nd `Select-Object` command.

The expression can be almost anything! Regardless of the question's shortcomings, this should be enough to create almost any column to want.  If you search Google for something like "PowerShell calculated property" you'll find tons of guidance and examples.

Comment: Steven, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Not sure I did the +1 vote correctly...
To all, so sorry about not mentioning detail structure.

Comment: Glad it's working. Hit the up arrow if you want to upvote +1.  Thanks!

Comment: I did :) unfortunately it won't show up as I am bit new to questions world.  The suggestion about "calculated property" that's what I was missing. I tried every other search criteria. Thank you once again.